# How to get a object id_type in python

Tags: python, scripting

Suppose I have a pointer of a object

```
obj = bpy.data.cache_files[0]
```

And I want to set the driver variable target to this object, so I need change the variable id_type before change the variable id

```
tar = fc.driver.variables[0].targets[0]
tar.id_type = "How to get the id_type of a unknown object?"
tar.id = obj
```

So I need a function to get a object id_type

```
def get_id_type(obj):
    ..
    return ".."
```

For example:

```
get_id_type(bpy.data.cache_files[0])
# >>>> "CACHEFILE"

get_id_type(bpy.data.objects[0])
# >>>> "OBJECT"

get_id_type(bpy.data.meshes[0])
# >>>> "MESH"
```

So far, I tried:

```
obj.rna_type.identifier
type(obj).__name__
```

that can't get what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script:

```
def get_id_type(obj):
    return obj.bl_rna.identifier.upper()

obj = bpy.data.cache_files[0]
id_type = get_id_type(obj)
```

**UPDATE**: As @[scurest](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/88681/scurest) has pointed out, due to a consistency issue, this will not work for *Light Probe* objects because of the inconsistent naming convention it uses. It is the only [`Id Type`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/id_type_items.html#rna-enum-id-type-items) enum with an underscore. So you will have to add an additional hacky hard-coded check:

```
def get_id_type(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, bpy.types.LightProbe):
        id_type = "LIGHT_PROBE"
    else:
        id_type = obj.bl_rna.identifier.upper()
    return id_type
```

Comment: I think this works except for the irregular form `LIGHT_PROBE`: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/id_type_items.html#rna-enum-id-type-items

Comment: @scurest ah very interesting you are right, it returns `LIGHTPROBE` without underscore. that's unfortunate but hopefully this type will not be needed by the OP lol. in addition, i believe the developers made a mistake in consistency, because this is the only type that uses an underscore. can we report this as a "bug" or at least as a consistency issue? i think they need to change that.